# Corda doorman for dummies

Tags: distributed, corda

I need to create a doorman in my test corda network but I do not understand how to do it.

I can't find any tutorial for the Corda doorman.

This page seems to be the only source of info on the doorman service: [Network permissioning(Doorman)](https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html)
It is really difficult to implement the doorman service just using this page.

I don't know what to do, can somebody explain the doorman for dummies?

Comment: If you can cut / paste what you have tried so far and any error messages you get, I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me so quickly. I've tried to understand the documentation and I also changed the node configuration several times until I understood that the doorman is not a Node's service (Notary,...) but rather a random HTTP server that will provide an API with both a GET /api/certificate/{requestId} and a POST /api/certificate endpoint. I still recommend a tutorial for dummies because it's quite confusing in the documentation as I am not the only one of my team who misunderstood it. Is it related in any way to HTTPS? I tried useHTTPS : true, in the node but it would not work.

Answer (score 4):

Pierre, I don't advise implementing your own Doorman - this would not be your time well-spent. Instead I suggest use standard tools and procedures to create, sign and distribute certificates to Corda nodes as specified in the ‘[Network Permissioning](https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html)’ section of the docs.

For when you start planning to deploy Corda to run real-world production workloads you would also be looking for a supported way of automating the management of network membership. Production deployments of Corda would also have other enterprise-grade requirements such as HA, DR, performance, manageability, compliance and security. These requirements will be addressed by upcoming release of Corda Enterprise. Naturally Doorman - the component which handles the management of network membership - will be part of Corda Enterprise.

For development and testing purposes there will be a stand-alone installable Doorman package with restricted license for non-production use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!